# How to import ZFS pool from backup drive

Tags: zfs

I have a USB external drive with a bckup of my system drive done via DD command.

When attach this USB drive to another system I can see the ZFS partition in DISKS as /dev/sdc3

How can I import this ZFS pool into the local system (even read-only) so I can browse the folders?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.